# How interpolate sin(1/x) in [-pi;pi]?

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have problem from interpolation in python. I must interpolate sin(1/x) in value section [-pi;pi] and interpolate data must be generate for 0.08 step. Entry data for 0.4 step. Problem is in values of entry data not ends in 3.14. The same situations is in interpolate data and i don't know how solve this. Two sets may equals. Here's my code to test this two sets:

```
import numpy as np

//entry x
x=[i for i in np.arange(-(np.pi),np.pi,0.4)]
print(x);

//interpolate x
xinterp=[i for i in np.arange(-(np.pi),np.pi,0.08)]
print(xinterp)
```

Comment: Probably due to the fact that floating point arithmetic doesn't work that way.

Comment: @duffymo How I can fix it?

Comment: I'd have to know more about how you're interpolating, but I think it's just a change in the looping construct you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to reflect tip by @wwii:*

This is expected behaviour. `arange` does not take stop as the final value and is not well defined for floating point...

From:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

> stop : number End of interval. The interval does not include this
>   value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating
>   point round-off affects the length of out.

Take a look a `linspace` instead.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html.

Which as per the description:

> Returns num evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval
>   [start, stop].

So in order to get the 0.8 granularity you'd need to have a number of steps equal to the width of the interval (2pi) divided by the granularity you want.

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, int(2 * np.pi / 0.08))
y = np.sin(1/x)
```

Comment: To obtain the OP's step size (or close to it) maybe: `x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, int(2 * np.pi / 0.08))`.

Comment: Ya! I was sort of just adding the example from the link so OP could take a look. Added your solution to the answer :)

Comment: @Caio Sym your solution it's working can you explain me how it works?

Comment: @PiotrStelmach Made a few changes. See if that explanation makes sense. lmk